# ASP.NET MVC 3 and jquery validation: does client validation support custom html controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, custom-controls

Preface: custom html-controls supposed to be following markup in partial view which is included in parent form:

```
    <select id="SomeModelFieldId" name="SomeModelFieldId">
         @{
                 <option value="">Select smthg...</option>

            foreach(var item in SomeModelFieldList)
            {
                 <option value="@item.Id">@item.Text</option>
            }
         }
    </select>
```

There is need to customize "option" behaviour by giving them additional attributes.

The issue is when I do something like that

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => SomeModelFieldId, new SelectList(SomeModelFieldList), "Select smthg...", new { })
```

validation works fine after submit happens [in other words on post back - it is acceptable for me], but if I change markup to previously mentioned validation engine does nothing.

I've compared markup generated with both mvc-supplied DropDownListFor-control and my custom markup - they seem to be the same... 
Am I missing smth? / Is it really impossible by design?

Comment: Are the control names the same?

Comment: @MystereMan, names and markup at whole completely the same as generated with MVC-engine. I even did some funny stuff and copied generated markup from firefox browser to my cshtml-page and the result is the same I described earlier.

Comment: That really doesn't make much sense.  If you're using unobtrusive validation, then data attributes get added to the generated HTML, so they wouldn't be the same.  And regardless, server side validation would be the same.

Comment: @MystereMan, I use jquery.validate plugin. jquery.validate.unobtrusive intenionally turned off. Did you try such experiment by yourself?..

Comment: Why do you have it turned off?  If you turn it on, does it work?

Comment: @MystereMan, the thing is I cannot enable unobtrusive. Functionality of jquery.validate should be enough for me: it marks incorrect input values after post back with red color.